ADO GitHub Connections - 'does not exist or has already been removed'
My team is using Github for SCM and Azure Boards to track our work.  I have setup a Github Connection in Project Settings and I have added repos from our Github Organization to that connection so that we can have our commits and PRs attached to our work items.  All of this was done in the ADO UI and the integration is working correctly.
Now I am trying to automate adding repos to this connection using the ADO APIs but the REST API consistently fails.
I am following the Microsoft documentation found here.
I have created a PAT with the Manage Connections scope to call the APIs referenced in that documentation.   The API call for /_apis/githubconnections?api-version=7.2-preview.1 works correctly and I get a list of the configured Github Connections for my project back.
Using the Connection ID that is returned in the previous call, I am unable to make calls to /_apis/githubconnections/{cnxid}/repos?api-version=7.2-preview.1 and /_apis/githubconnections/{cnxid}/reposBatch?api-version=7.2-preview.1
Both of those calls fail with an HTTP 500 and the message: "VS402656: The connection '{cnxid}' does not exist or has already been removed." The typekey is GitHubBoardsConnectionDoesNotExistException
I have verified that my Connection ID is correct, I have tried to see if there is a different ID I should be using, and so on but so far nothing I have done has worked.
I have tried doing this both from Postman and, at least in the case of getting the repository, from a browser as well.  Regardless of what I do I get the same exception.
Has anyone else run into this and/or is there a different set of APIs I should be referencing?

Hi @dparsons, Good day. Have you got a chance to check the answer below to use a PAT to the scope of vso.githubconnections? Hope it may help resolve your query in this post. We would also appreciate you may let us know the latest status of the issue or briefly introduce your solution, which may help others with similar concerns. Thx for the time and efforts.

Based on your description, a PAT with the scope to manage Service Connections was created for my test, against which I succeeded to authenticate to get GitHub connection id but failed in getting individual GitHub repo with the 401 error.
Having double check this document, I created a new PAT with the scope to manage GitHub Connections (vso.githubconnections), calling both APIs against the new PAT worked in my script.

$organization = "xxxMyOrgNamexxx"
$project = "xxxMyProjectxxx"
$MyPat = 'xxxMyPATScopedToGitHubServiceConnectionsxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))

$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}

$ghCnnsURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/githubconnections?api-version=7.2-preview.1"
$ghCnns = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $ghCnnsURL -Headers $headers
$ghCnns | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

$ghRepoURL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/githubconnections/2e5e5d79-2c9b-46db-a1ff-98cc362a5df7/repos?api-version=7.2-preview.1"
$ghRepo = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $ghRepoURL -Headers $headers
$ghRepo | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100


In case you have many other GitHub service connections, you may also leverage the browser developer tool to locate the id of the GitHub service connection you would like to get in the web UI of Project Settings.


Thanks for the answer.  I am not running into any authentication issues, just the 500.  I did create a PAT with all scopes to see if I had missed some permission, but I still have the same problem.  I talked to someone from the Azure Boards team and this appears to be an issue with Github Enterprise Server, the same flow for Github.com works fine.

Thanks a lot for your time to share the update. You may also provide the findings in the Developer Community as well. Please feel welcome to let us know the resolution here in SO. Thx again.
